# Display one single value from object array retrieved from a class on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, echo

I have an object that comes from a class on PHP which I load in an array like this:

```
$result2 = json_decode($etsyService->request('/receipts/12121212'));
```

When I `print_r` the array $result2, I get:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [count] => 1
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [receipt_id] => 1212121212
                    [order_id] => 1111111
                    [seller_user_id] => 2525252
                    [buyer_user_id] => ABCD
                    [creation_tsz] => 0000000
```

My question is, how can I `echo` one of these fields individually? For example just echo the seller_user_id (i.e. 2525252).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
echo $result2->results[0]->seller_user_id;
```

With `->` you access the object and then with `[]` you can access the array.

Answer (score 5):

The result is an object containing an array of objects. Use `->` for object properties and `[k]` for array elements:

```
echo $result2->results[0]->seller_user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the trail of objects / associative arrays that you see in your print_r output.

```
echo $result2->results[0]->receipt_id
```